# Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am invoking the web method of [Web Serivce](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl). When I ran this in my local machine it is working fine but while executing the same webmethod from my virtual machine it is not working and throwing the below exception at

```
NDFDWeatherForecast.ndfdXML objNDFD = new NDFDWeatherForecast.ndfdXML();
string strCurrent = objNDFD.GmlLatLonList(latlng, DateTime.Now, NDFDWeatherForecast.featureTypeType.Forecast_Gml2Point, Param);
```

Exception Message:

```
Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd"
version="1.0.0" language="en">
<Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="TIME"><ExceptionText>REQUEST values 2011-06-22T23:17:32.7201156-07:00 and/or 2011-06-22T23:17:32.7201156-07:00 are outside data window</ExceptionText></Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

**Note: I am developing a .net webapplication.**

Anybody has answer for this?

Comment: No help??... Do I need to explain little bit??

Answer (score 1):

Seems like web service you are calling doesn't like you date string `2011-06-22T23:17:32.7201156-07:00` which can be:

1. Invalid for a service (in the future, for example);
2. In invalid format (need to be in UTC, or in other string format, are you using same cultures on local and VM?).

Answer (score 0):

I have Same problem but by below suggestion being solved:

add a "Web Reference " instead of a "Service Reference". this will generate code based on .Net Framework 2.0 Web Services Technology.

so, in visual studio:

[*follow steps by Image tutorial*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ueEL.jpg)