# IBM Content Manager : Client found response content type of 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: c#, db2, content-management-system, websphere

I am trying to communicate IBM Content Manager Server using providing Web Services (using WSDL) while using C# .NET but I am getting response encoding error, I have tried many solutions already like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450106/client-found-response-content-type-of-text-html-charset-iso-8859-1-but-expec) and many others here is the image of error. [image]

how can I get rid from this problem??

Comment: The web service is returning html (eg 404 or 500 page). See view detail if it contains returned html